# Conditional expectation of nonnegative random variable is nonnegative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I know that if $X\geq 0$ then $E[X]\geq 0$. But if $\sigma$ is some sigma algebra, then is $E[X|\sigma]\geq 0$ a.s.?

What if we argue like this? Let $A=\{\omega\in \Omega: E[X|\sigma](\omega)<0\}$. Then $A$ is in $\sigma$ so $\int_A E[X|\sigma]=\int_A X\geq 0$ so $A$ has measure $0$.

But why is $A$ in $\sigma$?

Comment: $A$ is the preimage of a $\sigma$ measurable function, and is thus $\sigma$ measurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[X|\sigma]$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma$ and $A$ is the inverse image of $(-\infty,0)$ under this map.